# Filtering XML Parser Data

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

I plan to develop an application in order to retrieve a part of xml data from a file based on user input. My codes works well for retrieving the content of xml file but I can't figure out the best way to ask the parser to give me all the elements which are inside for example (intake name="TMF1202")... The user will give the intake name as input and parser will retrieve the elements that exist only in that intake tag, Here is my Parser code :

```
#import "Parser.h"
#import "TimeTableViewController.h"

@implementation Parser
@synthesize currentElementPointer, rootElement;

-(id)initParser
{
    if(self = [super init]) {
        tvc = (TimeTableViewController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

    if(self.rootElement == nil) {
        self.rootElement = [[List alloc]init];
        self.currentElementPointer = self.rootElement;
    } else {
        List *newList = [[List alloc]init];
        newList.parent = self.currentElementPointer;
        [self.currentElementPointer.subElements addObject:newList];
        self.currentElementPointer = newList;
    }

    self.currentElementPointer.name = elementName;
    self.currentElementPointer.attributes = attributeDict;

    // theList.intake = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"name"]stringValue];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if([self.currentElementPointer.text length] > 0) {
        self.currentElementPointer.text = [self.currentElementPointer.text stringByAppendingString:string];
    } else {
        self.currentElementPointer.text = string;
    }
}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    self.currentElementPointer = self.currentElementPointer.parent;
}

@end
```

This is the structure of my XML file :

[image: XML Format]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want this parser to work like it does, but simply not parse any elements (or subelements) of our XML document that are `intake` elements whose `name` attribute is not equal to `TMF1202`, you can employ a `BOOL` flag indicating whether you should be parsing this branch of the tree or not. E.g. one approach might be:

1. Create a `BOOL` property that designates whether you're currently parsing or not:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, getter = isParsing) BOOL parsing;
   ```
2. Make sure to initialize it:

   ```
   - (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
   {
       self.parsing = YES;
   }
   ```
3. If it encounters a `intake` whose `name` is not equal to `TMF1202`, your `didStartElement` can clear that `BOOL` value, perhaps something like:

   ```
   - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
   {
       if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"intake"])
       {
           NSString *name = attributeDict[@"name"];
           self.parsing = [name isEqualToString:@"TMF1202"];
       }

       if (![self isParsing]) return;

       // the rest of your standard parsing routine goes here
   }
   ```
4. Obviously, `foundCharacters` must also check to see if `isParsing`:

   ```
   -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
   {
       if (![self isParsing]) return;

       // the rest of your standard foundCharacters goes here
   }
   ```
5. And `didEndElement` should (a) only do the standard `didEndElement` stuff if `isParsing`; and (b) otherwise, if ending an `intake` reset the `parsing` flag:

   ```
   -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
   {
       if ([self isParsing])
       {
           // do your standard didEndElement stuff here
       }
       else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"intake"])
       {
           // otherwise, if we're ending an `intake`, then go ahead and turn parsing back on

           self.parsing = YES;
       }
   }
   ```

The details may vary (and there are lots of ways to tackle this), but this is one approach.

Comment: Despite its been mentioned not to say thanks on comments I couldn't resist not to say so on such a generous well defined answer. well Done Rob.